# How to add a closebutton to tab control with a different UI for each tab? 

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, contextmenu

How can i add a closebutton to my tab control?
this what my apps look like after i build and run. 
[image: after build and run]

if i choose Menu 1.1, after that Menu 2.2 it will show like this. 
[image: choose Menu 1.1, continue with Menu 2.2]

this is my usercontrol looks like. i have two usercontrols, one is for menu 1.1(left) and the others is for menu 1.2(right).

[image: usercontrol for menu 1.1]
[image: usercontrol for menu 2.1]

My question is:
1. is that possible to add the close button for each tab?
2. if yes, how can i do that?

I already follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem), but still can't make it. That link is using the same UI if you add a small title or long title. but now I have different UI for each tab. How can i handle the close button? thanks.

here is my xaml.

```
    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem Header="Menu 1" 
                        ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png" Name="RibbonSplit">
                    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Menu 1.1"
                                                  x:Name="RibbonMenu1"
                                                  ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png" Click="RibbonMenu1_Click"/>
                </ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>

                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem Header="Menu 2" ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png">
                    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Menu 2.1"
                                                  x:Name="RibbonMenu2"
                                                  ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png" Click="RibbonMenu2_Click"/>
                </ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>

            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

    </ribbon:Ribbon>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Height= "394" Name="TabMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    </TabControl>
```

here is the code how i add the tab,

```
tab2 tb1 = new tab1(); //menu1.1
AddTab(tb1);
```

here is my AddTab method,

```
if (_mdiChildren.ContainsKey(mdiChild.UniqueTabName))
        {
            //user control is already opened in tab. 
            //So set focus to the tab item where the control hosted
            foreach (object item in TabMenu.Items)
            {
                TabItem ti = (TabItem)item;
                if (ti.Name == mdiChild.UniqueTabName)
                {
                    ti.Focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //the control is not open in the tab item
            TabMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            TabMenu.Width = this.ActualWidth;
            TabMenu.Height = this.ActualHeight;

            //((ITabbedMDI)mdiChild).CloseInitiated += new delClosed(CloseTab);

            //create a new tab item
            TabItem ti = new TabItem();
            //set the tab item's name to mdi child's unique name
            ti.Name = ((ITabbedMDI)mdiChild).UniqueTabName;
            //set the tab item's title to mdi child's title
            ti.Header = ((ITabbedMDI)mdiChild).Title;
            //set the content property of the tab item to mdi child
            ti.Content = mdiChild;
            ti.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            ti.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            //add the tab item to tab control
            TabMenu.Items.Add(ti);
            //set this tab as selected
            TabMenu.SelectedItem = ti;
            //add the mdi child's unique name in the open children's name list
            _mdiChildren.Add(((ITabbedMDI)mdiChild).UniqueTabName, ((ITabbedMDI)mdiChild).Title);

        }
         //* */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these custom controls [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/04/08/CloseableTabItem.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem).

Comment: hi. thnks for you answer. I tried the link you sent to me already. For link no2, how if i have different UI form? link no2 is using the same UI form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hello.. i already update the question with pictures. Maybe you will be more understand.

Comment: This is a bit clearer. Thanks. But, what exactly the problem you're having with the suggested approach? What do you mean "but now I have different UI for each tab"?

Comment: different UI for each tab mean menu 1.1 and menu 2.1 have a different UI. you can see the pictures. so i can't use the link you reference to me because the link is assume you have the same tab.

Comment: If you mean content of the tab itself, you can still have different content. Instead of this <local:CloseableTabItem Header="TabItem 1"/> just expand the element and add its content inside it.

Comment: yes, the content itself.. how can i do it? i can't add the content inside, because in my xaml i just put <tabcontrol> </tabcontrol> without <tabitem>. the tabitem i add programmatically. so whenever user choose menu 1.1, i will add to the tabcontrol, AddTab(tab1). I already put the xaml at the question.